# Renaming File name in a folder

Tags: python, rename

I am doing udacity exercises. So I used the function 
 `os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate(str.maketrans('','','0123456789'))`  to remove numbers from filenames.  It worked on the output window, but didn't change the names in the intended folder. Help!

Comment: Do you know what `str.maketrans('','','0123456789')` is doing?

Comment: Hey! Not really . I know that it removes numbers from the strings . and the older version took two arguments and then I got an error saying that this function only takes one argument and I am giving it two .so I looked for an alternate function to remove names from file names in a folder in python 3 .. and found this. Please tell me if I need to know more about this. I am just starting of with python so really all input is very very welcome!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2 it sounds like you can do it like so:

```
new_file_name = str.translate(file_name,None,str.maketrans('','','0123456789'))
os.rename(file_name, new_file_name)
```

In Python 3.1+ It is done like so:

```
new_file_name = file_name.translate(str.maketrans('','','0123456789'))
os.rename(file_name, new_file_name)
```

You can also accomplish the same thing with the [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) function. It replaces all occurrences of one character with another character. I believe it is much more common to do the string replacement this way, but that is just because I don't think most people have ever heard of the string translate functions in the tutorial you found. I never have.

```
new_file_name = file_name
for char in '0123456789':
    new_file_name = new_file_name.replace(char, "")
os.rename(file_name, new_file_name)
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comments, you're going to want to do the following:

```
def rename_files(folder):

    #get file names from a folder
    file_list = os.listdir(folder)

    #for each file, rename filename to exclude any numbers
    for file_name in file_list:
        new_file_name = file_name.translate(str.maketrans('','','0123456789'))
        os.rename(file_name, new_file_name)
        print("renamed ", file_name, " to ", new_file_name)

rename_files('/Users/gazifah/Desktop/prank')
```

Comment: Hey ! Thank you for your reply! I tried both options and this is the error I get

 .NameError: name 'new_file_name' is not defined. 
How do I define the new_name?
Here is the my code. Please bare with me as I am really new to this.

import os
def rename_files():
    #get file names from a folder
    file_list= os.listdir('/Users/gazifah/Desktop/prank')
    print (file_list)

    #for each file,rename filename
    
new_file_name = file_name.translate(str.maketrans('','','0123456789'))
os.rename(file_name, new_file_name)

    
rename_files()

Comment: You're missing the line `for file_name in file_list:` to loop through all of the files in your file_list.